# html - scrollbar visible, but doesn't work

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, overflow

Very simple page, and the trouble... I'd like to scroll horizontally the table only. Scrollbar is visible and nothing more. Only the entire page is scrollable by the browser's scrollbar. If I set body to overflow:hidden there is no scrollbar at all. 
I'm very beginner at html and css. I think I've tried every advice, which I've found in the web... :-\

```css
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row::before,
.row::after {
    content:"";
    display: table ;
    clear: both;
}
body {
    background-color: #ebebeb;
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}
.header {
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 60px;
    background-color: #575757;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 60px;
}
.header h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
}
.rwd-table {
    max-width: 899px;
    width: 899px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <div class="header">
        <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="rwd-table">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Godzina</th>
                        <th>Śr, 10.01</th>
                        <th>Czw, 11.01</th>
                        <th>Pt, 12.01</th>
                        <th>So, 13.01</th>
                        <th>Nd, 14.01</th>
                        <th>Pn, 15.01</th>
                        <th>Wt, 16.01</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>7.00</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: is it possible that you dont have enough content so your table is not scrolling? Use min-width 3000px to make sure...

Comment: Yes. The rwd-table, at 899px wide, is wider than the table, so it doesn't have any scrollable content.

Answer (score 0):

First make **display:block** for your table
then set `overflow-x:auto` to your table instead of div and the scroll will appear auto

```css
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row::before,
.row::after {
    content:"";
    display: table ;
    clear: both;
}
body {
    background-color: #ebebeb;
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}
.header {
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 60px;
    background-color: #575757;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 60px;
}
.header h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
}
.rwd-table {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: aqua;
}
table {
    display: block;
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <div class="header">
        <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="rwd-table">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Godzina</th>
                        <th>Śr, 10.01</th>
                        <th>Czw, 11.01</th>
                        <th>Pt, 12.01</th>
                        <th>So, 13.01</th>
                        <th>Nd, 14.01</th>
                        <th>Pn, 15.01</th>
                        <th>Wt, 16.01</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>7.00</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much - it seems it works. I thought I've tried all combinations with display and overflow, assigned to div and to table. Apparently, however, not all...

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the **table** **class** a **width** grater than the **rwd-table** and the rwd-table div will be scrollable.

```
    .rwd-table {
        overflow-x: scroll;
        width: 500px;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: aqua;

    }
    .table{
        width: 5000px;
    }
```

Comment: You Could aslo use A. Bechir answer but you need to give the table class a width and convert the overflow-x: from auto to scroll.